# Laravel optional columns on default values

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

My `group` column in my responses table has a default value of "city". My code below does a lookup to see if the default value should go in... or some other value;

```
$group = Group::where('token', $request->input('groupToken'))->first();

$group = ($group ? $group->value : 'city');

$response = Response::create([
    'token' => $token,
    'group' => $group,
]);
```

Ideally I want to get rid of this `$group = ($group ? $group->value : 'city');` line and just not pass in `$group` to the `create()` method if the `Group::where` returns null.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$group = Group::where('token', $request->input('groupToken'))->first();

$data['token'] = $token;

if($group != null){
    $data['group'] = $group->value;
}

$response = Response::create($data);
```

Comment: of course. `$data` vs an array of data. it's the same thing! how silly of me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `->first()` you can use `firstOrFail()` and wrap it in a `try-catch`, if none is returned then it will throw a `ModelNotFoundException`.

Something like (untested):

```
$data['token'] = $token;
try {
    $group = Group::where('token', $request->input('groupToken'))->firstOrFail();
    $data['group'] = $group;
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
    // Handle exception
}

$response = Response::create(
    $data
);
```